# How do I declare a variable in ASP that can be used by multiple users?

Tags: asp-classic

How do I declare a variable in ASP that can be used by multiple users? 
I know I can use SESSION to declare a variable that can be seen by the same user across multiple pages, but I need a variable that can be seen by any user accessing the server. It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Application object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525360(v=vs.90).aspx

You can "use" it the same way as a Session variable:

```
Application("foo") = "Message to all users"
```

It is global for all users and is perfect to use as a cache for data that is equal for all users.